# Where can I ask about the history of medicine?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Specifically, I have a couple questions about what medical knowledge and capabilities existed in the Roman Empire, specifically Judaea, during the 1st century AD. Is there a Stack Exchange site where I could ask them?

These are the specific questions:

- Was it understood in the 1st century that some diseases are sexually transmitted?
- Is it likely that a person could have survived long-term after an injury that resulted in a piece of wood being embedded in his body in a way that 1st century medicine could not remove?

Answer (score 10):

Our [history of science and mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) site states:

> is a question and answer site for people interested in the history and
> origins of science and mathematics.

The have many questions relating to Galen's, Hyppocrates's surgical and medical practices and of course beliefs.

Similarly, our [history](https://history.stackexchange.com/) site produces numerous results for the search terms {Roman Medicine}. Syphilis and hygiene practices are mentioned.

As ever, be sure to take their tours and read in their help centre about how best to ask a question according to their individual site ways.

Comment: Thank you! I posted one of my questions on History of Science and Mathematics.